# DB Schema Creation In a Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am wondering how DB schema is created in a project using Spring Data JPA. I create a Spring Boot project with the Spring Data JPA and H2. While the project works as desired, I can't figure how the DB schema is created. My search on "create table" returns nothing. I haven't found any related information on my online search. For my next project, I would like to use PostgreSQL for its JSon data type. That would request some changes on the DB schema somehow because the JSon isn't a standard DB data type.

Comment: "My search on "insert into" returns nothing" - is it from console with option show_sql ?

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped. It should be "create table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA has features for DDL generation, and these can be set up to run on startup against the database. This is controlled through two external properties:

> spring.jpa.generate-ddl (boolean) switches the feature on and off and
>   is vendor independent. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto (enum) is a
>   Hibernate feature that controls the behavior in a more fine-grained
>   way.

You can output the schema creation by enabling the org.hibernate.SQL logger. This is done for you automatically if you enable the debug mode

---

Also for : " I can't figure how the DB schema is created. My search on "insert into" returns nothing."

"schema is created" -  it's ddl operation like create , drop ... see [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)

"My search on "insert into" returns nothing." - it's just insert into a table, it doens't create a table

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. Is a way to handle a non-standard relational DB data type with DDL?

Comment: Yiu need support Dialects. Check what dialects suport by hibernate  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html. if you db not in the list you shold create your custom dialect